# This item is not compatible with your device on Samsung GT-S5360, whereas I can install/test on my device

Tags: android, android-manifest, compatibility

I am getting a strange error on Android Market. I am not able to download my app due to the following error - "This item is not compatible with your device".

As I am the developer of this app, I can install and run this successfully, however Android Market is throwing me an error. Any resolutions, ideas? What kind of filter is applied by Android, can I resolve that by adding any tag in my manifest file?

Here is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.smartscreen_chnagedname"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity android:name="act_MainSmartScreen"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges = "orientation"
android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name="Ser_ServiceStartupIntentReceiver"      android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="serv_MainSmartScreen">

</service>
<activity android:name="act_ListViewForSelectingApps"
android:screenOrientation = "portrait"></activity>
<activity android:name="act_ListViewForSelectionAlbums"
android:screenOrientation = "portrait"></activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding uses-feature, enabled whole world for us. Camera/Wifi/Bluetooth/telephony/mic was optional for our app. Adding android:required="false" to uses-feature did the trick for us.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
 android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add below lines to your manifest file and see if it solves your problem.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

Comment: <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />

Comment: Worked for my project which has `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>`